# How do I vertically center <aside> elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center the three `<aside>` elements. As you can see, they are aligned more towards the right side.

```
     <aside>
      <section>
        <div class="container">
          <nav>
            <ul class="center">
              <a><li>Home</li></a>
              <a><li>Projects</li></a>
              <a><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
    </aside>
```

CSS

```
body{
  margin: auto;
}

.container{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a padding on the ul element. You need to make ul {padding: 0} or better: make padding 0 on all elements with * {padding: 0} this removes the padding bydefault.

[image: boxmodel]

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css:

```
ul{
  padding:0;}
```

```css
body{
  margin: auto;
}

.container{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<aside>
      <section>
        <div class="container">
          <nav>
            <ul class="center">
              <a><li>Home</li></a>
              <a><li>Projects</li></a>
              <a><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out in JSFiddle, and the text seemed much more center-aligned when I did

```
.container{text-align: left;}
```